# __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: '_interactive__interact_f'

Tags: python, init

I had this error message when I run my code. What parameter is missing?

I use ipywidgets for the first time and I am not sure what did I wrong, the code runs but error message pops up.

````
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import Dropdown

def scatter_plot_int_with_hue(x = 'Export_Value_Index',y = 'Export_Quantity_Index', hue = 'Country'):
    plt.figure(dpi = 120)
    sns.set_style('whitegrid')
    return sns.scatterplot(data = df, x = x, y = y, alpha = 0.6, hue = hue, cmap = 'Set2').set_title('Visualize Relation Between 2 Quantative Variables with Hue')

B = interact(scatter_plot_int_with_hue,
             x = widgets.Dropdown(
                 options = ['Export_Quantity_Index','Export_Unit/Value_Index',
    'Export_Value_Base_Price','Export_Value_Base_Quantity','Export_Value_Index','PPI','Livestock_value']
                 ),
             y = widgets.Dropdown(
                 options = ['Export_Quantity_Index','Export_Unit/Value_Index',
    'Export_Value_Base_Price','Export_Value_Base_Quantity','Export_Value_Index','PPI','Livestock_value']
                 ),
              hue = widgets.Dropdown(
                 options = ['Country', 'Item']
                 ) 
            )
interactive(children=(Dropdown(description='x', options=('Export_Quantity_Index','Export_Unit/Value_Index',
    'Export_Value_Base_Price','Export_Value_Base_Quantity','Export_Value_Index','PPI','Livestock_value'))))```
````

Comment: traceback please.

Comment: Based on nothing more than your title, I'm guessing that `interactive` wants to be passed an `interact`.  If so, you need to pass `B` as the first parameter.